# Set default site for users in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to achieve the following;

There are 5 sites, with links between them for navigation, one of them being the main page we want users to start on, let's call it "Main". How and where do I set this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nearly two years later... still can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the OP will ever come back to this, but my understanding of the question is that they have 5 sites/collections and want one of them to be the primary and the other, by navigation, to be secondary.  While both previous answers will allow you to define which page is shown for the home page of a site, what you are looking for is the **Portal Site Connection**.  It is found in the site settings of the top level of a site collection and will change the breadcrumb to have a the "Main" site as the hub for the rest.

Its description is "Define a parent site that will appear in this site's breadcrumb navigation."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Site settings* and under *Look and Feel* open *Welcome Page*. Here define the URL for your main page.
Alternative possibilities for 2007 & 2010 versions of SP are listed [here](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.fi/2011/06/sharepoint-how-to-change-default-home.html), but you'd be just fine with the settings option.

---

Edit: To set the home page ("main page") on SharePoint Designer, follow these orders from [MSDN](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c0c23de-8003-4b20-a0cd-d62b479da6c3/how-to-set-another-page-as-the-public-website-default-page-in-sharepoint-online):

> 1. Start Microsoft Sharepoint Designer 2010
> 2. Open Site to type in your public site’s URL and login with an administrator account
> 3. Click All files from the left navigation bar and click Pages(Web Pages)
> 4. Click the quadrate icon before "news.aspx" and click Set at Home Page from the top ribbon.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The issue however is unresolved as there is no "welcome page" under Look & Feel" This is for Sharepoint Online.

Comment: Find my updated answer above. I wish I had an SP Online to use and see for myself its limitations.

Comment: If you are unable to see link 'Welcome Page', then Go to Site Collection Feature & Site Features and from both activate Publishing features..

Answer (score 0):

Open the site using SharePoint designer and right click on your page and select "Set as Home Page" option. 
[image: Select Set as Home Page]